# getCallerMetadata() and getCallerCert() not found in Hyperledger fabric v1.0

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I was trying to build the [asset_management.](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/examples/chaincode/go/asset_management)go chaincode using the Fabric v1.0 codebase , but it fails because `getCallerMetadata()` and `getCallerCert()` is not found in stub. Is there a replacement for these functions in v1.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@cjcroix - you can use `GetCreator()` [function](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L106) in place of `getCallerCert()`

I don't think that the caller metadata is relevant anymore with the new messages, but you can use the transient field in the proposal to pass in any extra info needed for authentication/authorization in chaincode and you can access it using the `GetTransient()` [function](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L113)

We are also eventually thinking about passing the entire proposal request into the chaincode as well in the future.  That work was started [here](https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/#/c/6205/)